Need comprehensive documentation for MS Entra ID auth for a backend/frontend webapp
I was asked to implement authentication in my backend app using MS Entra ID
The backend app fetches data from the MS Graph API with Azure AD OAuth tokens, processes it and stores it in a mongoDB. That part was built already and works.
Now we want users to be able to sign in the the frontend (NextJS) and view the processed data in the database using a NestJS/Express backend.
The frontend auth with Entra ID also already works successfully with NextAuth.
I analyzed the HTTP requests and responses during the auth of the frontend. The cookie contains a token that looks like a JWT but is not a valid JWT. It has 4 dots in it instead of 3.
From what I found out on searching, that might be an opaque access token.
How would I use this?
When calling GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me with header Authorization: Bearer <the token from the cookie> I get the error
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "NoDecryptionKeysInPolicy",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "<date>",
      "request-id": "<id>",
      "client-request-id": "<id>"
    }
  }
}

I read a lot in the Microsoft documentation but I can't figure out how to handle the auth in the backend to see what AD groups the user is in and deny access in my NestJS guard when the user is not in a certain group
All the examples Microsoft provides either use the App Service x-ms-token header but I want to be able to host the app anywhere, not only on Azure.
Can anyone guide me to the right docs or a full step by step tutorial? Had no luck searching the web for two hours now.
Searched the web
Asked Microsoft QA AI Assistant
Read the MS Graph Docs
No luck so far :/
